# ntpd running as non-root, but outgoing packets match as uid 0

Tags: iptables, ntpd

I set my default iptables OUTPUT chain to DROP packets. I then created a firewall rule to only allow the ntp user to send ntp packets out:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner ntp -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
```

However, every 10-20 minutes I would see:

```
ntpd[27769]: sendto(<snip>) (fd=22): Operation not permitted
```

I then removed the `-m owner --uid-owner ntp` portion of the rule and added a log rule before it:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j LOG --log-level debug \
    --log-prefix "Spotted a NTP packet: " --log-uid
```

`ntpd` started working again, and in the kernel ring buffer, I see:

```
Spotted a NTP packet: <snip> PROTO=UDP SPT=123 DPT=123 LEN=56 UID=0
```

I'm using the `--log-uid` switch to the `LOG` target, and `ntpd` is running as the ntp user (uid=38):

```
# ps auxf | grep ntpd
ntp      27769  0.0  1.0   4512  4508 ?        SLs  Jan04   0:00 ntpd -u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid
```

Yet the log shows `UID=0`. I'm positive nothing else on the system is sending out ntp packets, and since I'm no longer getting the `Operation not permitted`, I'm certain it is in-fact `ntpd` that's sending the packet.

I guess I'm fine with not matching the ntp user for these packets; however, **can someone explain why iptables isn't showing** `UID=38` **for these packets?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a program to use a port less then 1024 it must be root.  Many applications like NTP will start, open the port as root, and then drop privileges to some defined account for everything else.

Comment: Apache starts as root and drops its privileges just like ntp does, yet outgoing packets for apache do in-fact match the apache UID. So I'm not convinced that's the reason.

Comment: They are obviously very different programs.  Just because it is possible to make things show up correctly doesn't mean that it does.  For example the most common Apache MPM forks and dup()'s lots of processes and uses tcp.  NTP is mostly udp-based, and is a single process.  I am sure someone who knew the ntp source could tell you for certain, but I am pretty confident that what I suggest is the case for ntp.

Comment: Okay, you've convinced me :) I guess my question now is, what code makes this distinction, but that is probably better asked on stackoverflow. Thanks.

Comment: Actually depending on how you ask the question you might get a better answer on security or programmers.  I suspect someone over on security knows what existing software does, and someone over on programmers could answer the question about how to open a port and drop all privileges.  I wonder if you could set ntp to listen to a >1024 and then setup iptables nat rules to redirect ntp traffic to the right place, it might not stay root, if it binds to a high port.

Answer (score 1):

There are mistake in Your iptables rule:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner ntp -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
```

If You use **--uid-owner** it is necessary to define **uid** - numeric value.
For the program name You need another option: **--cmd-owner**. Correct rule is:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --cmd-owner ntp -p udp --dport 123 -j
```

Detailed explanation You may read in great [book](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html#OWNERMATCH) by *Oskar Andreasson*.